# What is the security impact of having a buggy function evaluating regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, security, exploit

Imagine that PHP (or JS) has a flaw in its regular expression matching function `preg_match(...)`. **For the same parameters**, sometimes it gives a match, sometimes it doesn't.

What security issues can arise from this? Can this function be exploited server-side (or client-side, in JS case)?

**EDIT:** For example, imagine I have a string STR, a regex pattern PTR and a matching function MATCH(STR, PTR) which returns *true* or *false* if the string matches the pattern or not, resp.

Consider that I execute the following code:

```
STR = ...;
PTR = ...;
MATCH(STR, PTR); // will return true
MATCH(STR, PTR); // will return false
MATCH(STR, PTR); // will return true
MATCH(STR, PTR); // will return false
```

So, for the same values PTR, STR, the function will return different (apparently non-deterministic) outputs. How severe is this issue?

Note: This does not happen with all values of PTR and STR, but there is a good amount of possible values for PTR and STR which trigger this problem.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Ok. I have edited the OP.

Comment: Its going to be a security concern. What specific issues? Would depend on the context. The greater concern is whatever is causing your MATCH function to return different values for the same inputs.

Comment: It really depends on the context the regex is used. Imagine that an input sanitizer is built on top of a buggy regex engine - the input will not be properly sanitized, so it may allow arbitrary code injection